# On Mac, run simple example of qglViewer. Error with lGLU

Tags: qglviewer

I am new to qglViewer, and I am using Mac. I install qglViewer, qt by homebrew, and I want to run some example of qglViewer.

However, I meet the following error:

[image: Compile Output]

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks!

EDIT: I don't know how to install libgl1-mesa-dev on Mac. Thinks...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've managed to compile all the projects included (QGLViewer, examples, contrib and plugin) manually editing each .pro file commenting each line :

```
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL *= -lGLU
```

there is one instance per .pro file

Probably it is not the best choice, but I was in a hurry and it was the fastest solution I have found.